# Program doesn't stop when it's supposed to, and how to I fix this?

Tags: c, char, printf

I have to make a program for school in which I have to print memory as both bytes and characters. The problem is that when I enter an amount that isn't a multiple of the LINE_WIDTH that character stream doesn't stop printing while the byte stream does. I used the same method with both but I don't know why it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea?

This is the code:

```
void output(long int *sA, int*dSz)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(abs(i)<abs(*dSz))
    {
        unsigned char* address = (unsigned char*)(*sA);
        if(*dSz>0)
        {
            printf("\n%#lx\t",(*sA+i));
            for(int a=0;a<LINE_WIDTH;a++)
            {
                if(i==*dSz)
                {
                    printf("   ");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%.2X ",toupper(address[i]));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            i=i-LINE_WIDTH;
            for(int a=0;a<LINE_WIDTH;a++)
            {
                if(isprint(address[i]))
                    {
                    if(i==*dSz)
                    {
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%c ",address[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if(i==*dSz)
                        {
                            exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf(". ");
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And this is my output:

Address of main function in memory is: 0x10084a830
Address of first local variable of main<> on the function stack is: 0x7fff5f3b5ba8

```
Enter the start address (hex-notation) of dump: 7fff5f3b5ba8

Enter the number of bytes to dump <negative or positive value>: 25

Address     Bytes               Chars
--------    -----------------------------   -------------------
0x7fff5f3b5ba8  A8 5B 3B 5F FF 7F 00 00 E0 5B   . [ ; _ . . . . . [ 
0x7fff5f3b5bb2  3B 5F FF 7F 00 00 01 00 00 00   ; _ . . . . . . . . 
0x7fff5f3b5bbc  00 00 00 00 D0                  . . . . . . . . . .
```

As you can see the bytes stop where they are supposed to, but the chars don't.

Comment: Hi.  That is way too much code for a SO question.  Please boil this down to a much simpler minimal test-case that demonstrates the same symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you're wrong:

```
i=i-LINE_WIDTH;
```

The cycle preceding this code would not always increase `i` by `LINE_WIDTH`, the number could be less. You need to subtract only as much as you add.

Same goes for second part with

```
i=i+LINE_WIDTH;
```

Comment: I thought that too, but when I change it to i=i-(LINE_WIDTH-1), which would set i back to 0, the bytes and the corresponding character don't match, now they do. LINE_WIDTH is a predefined constant, here 10.

Comment: The tail in your example is 5 bytes long, LINE_WIDTH is 10. In the first cycle `i++;` would only be executed 5 times, and then you subtract 10 from that. How do you think you would be working with the same sequence in the next loop if `i` is 5 bytes behind?